Get vulnerabilities per image in Azure
Container images in Azure registry does provide the list of images but doesn't provide the vulerabilites per image. In Defender for Cloud we can see a list of vulnerabilities, but only for all the images. Is there a way in Azure to see the vulnerabilities per image?
Edit
We found all the images related to a vulnerability:
CVS-24038 -> image:tag1, image:tag2, etc.
We would like to list all vulnerabilities per image:
image:tag1 -> CVS-24038, CVS-24039, etc.
The goal is to be able to know for each image which vulnerabilities it has.
Edit 2
A good example for what we are looking for is Docker Hub, (for example the alpine image hub.docker.com/_/alpine/tags) which let us know all vulnerabilities per image. Unfortunatly we weren't able to get this information using Defender for Cloud.

Is this what you're looking for? View vulnerabilities on a specific container image

Thank you @RuiJarimba for your answer. I edited my previous question to add that we already found all the images related to a vulnerability: CVS-24038 -> image:tag1, image:tag2, etc. Our need is to list all vulnerabilities per image: image:tag1 -> CVS-24038, CVS-24039, etc.

Yes, in Defender for Cloud, you can view vulnerabilities per image. As correctly pointed out by Rui Jarimba
To do so, follow these steps:

Open the Recommendations page in Defender for Cloud.
If you're not on the new risk-based page, select Recommendations by risk on the top menu.
If issues were found, you'll see the recommendation "Container images in Azure registry should have vulnerability findings resolved". Select the recommendation.
The recommendation details page opens with additional information. This information includes details about your registry image and the remediation steps.
Select the Findings tab to see the list of vulnerabilities impacting the registry image.
Select each vulnerability for a detailed description of the vulnerability, additional images affected by that vulnerability, information on the software version that contributes to resolving the vulnerability, and links to external resources to help with patching the vulnerability.





Currently, Azure doesn't provide a direct command or single interface to display all vulnerabilities listed per image in the format "image:tag -> CVE-12345, CVE-67890" . However, you can achieve this by accessing the Defender for Cloud's vulnerability findings and processing the data accordingly as shown in the above screenshot. You can group recommendations by title. For more information, see the "Group recommendations by title" section in the "View and remediate vulnerabilities for registry images (Risk based)" article.
References:

View and remediate vulnerabilities for registry images (Risk based)
Vulnerability assessments for Azure with Microsoft Defender Vulnerability Management


Thank you for your detailled answer. We really need to know for a specific image and tag which vulnerability applies to it, as it is the case in Docker Hub, for example with the alpine image (https://hub.docker.com/_/alpine/tags). Unfortunatly we weren't able to get this information using Defender for Cloud.
